# How can I accumulate Dataframes in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I know Spark Streaming produces batches of RDDs, but I'd like to accumulate one big Dataframe that updates with each batch (by appending new dataframe to the end).

Is there a way to access all historical Stream data like this?

I've seen mapWithState() but I haven't seen it accumulate Dataframes specifically.

Answer (score 1):

While Dataframes are implemented as batches of RDDs under the hood, a Dataframe is presented to the application as an non-discrete infinite stream of rows.  There are no "batches of dataframes" as there are "batches of RDDs".

It's not clear what historical data you would like.

Comment: Say each batch of RDDs is like so: 123, 456, 789..  I'd like to collect all this into one single Dataframe, or somehow combine all these RDDs into a dataframe, like 123456789... and all new data is appended to this dataframe. And this dataframe should be accessible right after appending the new data. The main reason for this is so I can re-fit a model that requires all data seen thus far.